# Make a sprite behave like a rigid body in Phaser.io

Tags: game-physics, phaser-framework

I am trying to create a little simulation with Phaser.IO. The idea is implement simulate something like a box where you can let balls (or some other polygon) fall.

The polygon must behave like a rigid body when dropped (IE. collide with other balls and the box wall)

I have implemented (sort of) that using [Physics.js](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/):
http://jsbin.com/poxehenu/1

Now, I want to implement the same with Phaser.IO, but could not find a way to make the balls collide with other balls like they collide with the world bounds.

I came to this: http://jsbin.com/pozoy/4

Is that possible with Phaser.IO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the P2 Physics system that comes with Phaser. Have a look at the [Phaser Examples](http://examples.phaser.io) and scroll down to the P2 section specifically. There should be plenty of examples there to get you started, then you can use the [API docs](http://docs.phaser.io) to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Thank you. I was in a psycotic code frenzy and overlooked P2 physics completely. Phaser.IO is great!